# How and where to use javax.swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

Please help, I'm trying to use javax.swing.Timer in my program. I have looked at lots of examples, but it still doesn't make sense to me. I am writing a program that has the user guessing the price. What I can't seem to figure out is how to have a timer that counts down from 30 seconds after the "new Game" button is clicked. If the user has not guessed the correct answer, then I want the game to display "You lose", but I also want the timer to stop if they get the correct answer in under 30 seconds and display that time. I believe I'm suppose to use

```
 timer = new Timer(Speed, this); 
 timer.start();
 timer.end();
```

but, I'm not sure what else I need for the timer or where to place these within my code. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is the code for my program...

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class ClockGame extends JFrame {

   //Declare fields for GUI components
   private JTextField guessField;
   private JButton newGameButton;
   private JLabel messageLabel;
   private JLabel guessLabel;
   private ImageIcon clockImage;
   private int countTotal;
   private Random rand;
   private JLabel title;
   private int number;
   private Timer timer;

   public ClockGame() {
     //Build GUI
     super ("Clock Game");
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     //Set layout
     this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     //Create the main panel
     JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

     //Create components and place them in the panel
     rand = new Random();

     guessLabel = new JLabel("Guess: ");
     guessField = new JTextField(20);
     messageLabel = new JLabel("                             Click New Game to Begin");
     clockImage = new ImageIcon("clock.jpg");
     newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
     title = new JLabel("The Clock Game", clockImage, SwingConstants.CENTER);

     //Set font for clockGameLabel
     title.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 24));

     //Set messageLabel Color
     messageLabel.setOpaque(true);
     messageLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

     newGameButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
     guessField.addActionListener(new AnswerListener());

     //Add components to the panel
     mainPanel.add(guessLabel);
     mainPanel.add(guessField);
     mainPanel.add(newGameButton);
     this.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     this.add(messageLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

     //Add the panel to this JFrame
     this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

     //Sizes this JFrame so that it is just big enough to hold the components
     this.setSize(340,225);

     //Make the JFrame visible on the screen
     this.setVisible(true);
   }

   private class AnswerListener implements ActionListener {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       //Code to check to see if answer is correct
       int sum = number;
       int answer = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());
       Color purple = new Color(153, 153, 253);

       countTotal++;
       if (sum < answer)
       {
         messageLabel.setText("Too High");
         messageLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
       }
       else if (sum > answer)
       {
         messageLabel.setText("Too Low");
         messageLabel.setBackground(purple);
       }
       else
       {
         messageLabel.setText("Correct! It took you " + countTotal + " tries, in " +
                          timer + " seconds");
         messageLabel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
       }
     }
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       number = rand.nextInt(1001);
       messageLabel.setText("              The price is between $1 and $1000, begin.");
       messageLabel.setBackground(Color.green);
      countTotal = 0;
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     ClockGame frame = new ClockGame();
   }
 }
```

Comment: You don't literally use those three lines. Try reading this example code  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingTimers.htm

Comment: You need a actionlistener for timer to run once a count reaches 30 and increments 1 per second

Answer (score 2):

```
timer.end();
```

There is no `end()` method. First you need to read the API for the appropriate method to use.

> counts down from 30 seconds after the "new Game" button is clicked.

So in the `ActionListener` you add to the button you need to start the Timer and schedule it to fire every second. When the Timer fires you decrement your count by 1.

> I also want the timer to stop if they get the correct answer

So when they get the correct answer you stop the Timer. So in your code where you update the text of the label you stop the Timer.

> If the user has not guessed the correct answer, then I want the game to display "You lose",

So when the timer count reaches 0, you 1) stop the timer and 2) display the message.

In the constructor of you class you would actually create the Timer, so that the above methods in your class have a reference to the Timer so it can be started and stopped as required.

What you really need to do is forget about your game and learn how to use a Timer. So you create a frame with a label and two buttons. The label will display the initial count of 30. Then you have a "Start" button that decrements the label by 1 each time the Timer fires. Then you have a "Stop" button that stops the Timer so the count is not decremented.

Once you understand the basic concept of starting and stopping the Timer, then you add the code to your real program.

Answer (score 1):

Well to begin... you would need a JLabel that is assigned to print "You lose" and another one that prints the Time that it took the player to answer the question. Add these to your Frame however you want.

```
 JLabel outcome = new JLabel(); //setText to win or lose.
 JLabel countdown = new JLabel(); //setTime as Timer counts down.
```

After you have instantiated these Labels. The Timer needs to be instantiated.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() { //Change parameters to your needs.
        int count = 30; 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           count--;
           if(count == 0) //They lose
           {
              countdown.setText("CountDown: " + count);
              outcome.setText("You Lose");
              timer.stop(); //ends the countdown.
           }
           else if(userGotAnswer) // You need to create a boolean value that changes when a user gets the answer right.
           {
               countdown.setText("CountDown: " + count);
               outcome.setText("You win");
               timer.stop(); //ends the countdown      
           }
           else
           {
               countdown.setText("CountDown: " + count); //default
           }
        }
    });
```

Then call

```
timer.start();
```

when you want the timer to start.